# Projectile not originating from the correct location

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to make a SKSpriteNode come from a SKShapeNode. When the below code runs, the projectiles are appearing, but they will originate from a different point on the screen, not the player location. 
Here is my shoot function that is in my Player Class.

```
func shoot() { 

            let newProjectile = Projectile()
            newProjectile.position = self.position

           self.addChild(newProjectile)
            let action = SKAction.moveTo(CGPointMake(
                600 * -cos(newProjectile.zRotation - 1.57079633) + newProjectile.position.x,
                600 * -sin(newProjectile.zRotation - 1.57079633) + newProjectile.position.y
            ), duration: 2.0)

            let actionMoveDone = SKAction.removeFromParent()
            newProjectile.runAction(SKAction.sequence([action, actionMoveDone]))
            }
```

Here is my Projectile Class :

```
    class Projectile : SKSpriteNode {

        let Texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "image.png")

        static var counter : Int = 0

        init(){
            //super.init()
            super.init(texture: Texture, color: UIColor.whiteColor(), size: CGSize(width: radius * 2, height: radius * 2))
            self.name   = "projectile-" + NSUUID().UUIDString
            self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: radius)
            self.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = GlobalConstants.Category.projectile
            self.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = GlobalConstants.Category.projectile
            self.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = GlobalConstants.Category.projectile | GlobalConstants.Category.wall
            self.zPosition = GlobalConstants.ZPosition.projectile
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you probably need to add your projectiles to the scene instead of the player itself.  you're adding the projectiles to your player.

you should add the projectile to the parents scene.  something like this.

```
self.scene!.addChild(newProjectile)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the projectiles to be children of the player, then the projectile's position must be expressed in terms of the player i.e. A position of (0, 0) will place the projectile at the player's anchor point.

If you want the projectiles to be children of the scene, then the projectile's position will be expressed in terms of the scene i.e. a position equal to the player's position will be needed to put the projectile on top of the player.

You combined the two, causing the projectile to be placed with the (x,y) position of the player in the scene, but relatIve to the player, which means that wherever the player is compared to the scene's origin, then that's where the projectile will appear relative to the player.

Comment: Thanks! Actually both of your answers helped. All I had to do was instead of: self.addChild(newProjectile), I put self.addChild(self.newProjectile)